# How to make the value of a claim in wikidata a hyperlink or link to another external page

Tags: json, hyperlink, wikidata, wikidata-api, wikibase

I am trying to create a script in Wikidata that creates a claim for certain entities. The claim should have a property of "external identifier" and a value that is the identifier generated by an external organization. Additionally, I want the value to be a hyperlink that directs the user to the organization's page when clicked.

To clarify, I want the variable "objectIdentifier" to be displayed as text, but when clicked, it should redirect to "redirectURL", the organization's page. The identifier is an alphanumeric code, and I am currently unable to make it into a hyperlink using my current function.

Here is the function I am using to create the claim:

```
def writeStatement(apiUrl, editToken, subjectQNumber, propertyPNumber, objectIdentifier, redirectURL):

    parameters = {
        'action': 'wbcreateclaim',
        'format': 'json',
        'entity': subjectQNumber,
        'snaktype': 'value',
        'bot': '1', 
        'token': editToken,
        'property': propertyPNumber,
        'value': '"' + objectIdentifier + '"',
        'url': redirectURL
    }
    r = session.post(apiUrl, data=parameters)
    data = r.json()
    return data
```

However, the function currently only writes the identifier as plain text without creating a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a [formatter URL](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1630) on the property might be all that’s needed.